# Deck of cards, dealing alternately

Tags: python, playing-cards

```
import random
import itertools    
suit = 'CSHD'
rank = '23456789TJQKA'
deck_of_cards = [''.join(card) for card in itertools.product(rank, suit)]

def draw_card(deck,hand, count):
    for i in range(count):
        hand.append(deck.pop())

def hand_selection(deck):
    shuffled_deck = random.sample(deck, len(deck))
    dealer_hand = []
    player_hand = []
    draw_card(shuffled_deck, dealer_hand, 1)
    draw_card(shuffled_deck, player_hand, 1)
    draw_card(shuffled_deck, dealer_hand, 1)
    draw_card(shuffled_deck, player_hand, 1)
    return dealer_hand,player_hand
```

Trying to follow the principle of card dealing here. Initially I wanted to generate a card randomly, remove it from the `shuffled_deck`, but we don't deal cards by randomly scouring through the deck, are we? For my purpose, the code does what it is supposed to do, but it doesn't look too good. *(Yes, the `shuffled_deck`, `player_hand` and `dealer_hand` are all globals actually, but it's irrelevant for the moment.)*

What would be a more elegant(read: pythonic) solution to deal cards in this manner? E.g were we playing something like Chinese poker between, say, 3 players. Dealing one by one like this seems too tedious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make the deck a class, to keep its related functionality together:

```
class Deck(object):

    def __init__(self, suits='CSHD', ranks='23456789TJQKA'):
        self.cards = [''.join(card) for card in itertools.product(ranks, suits)]

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal_cards(self, hand, count=1):
        for _ in range(count):
            hand.append(self.cards.pop())

    def return_cards(self, hand):
        self.cards.extend(hand)
```

And to simplify the dealing:

```
deck = Deck()
deck.shuffle()
dealer_hand = []
player_hand = []
for _ in range(2): # number of rounds to deal
    for hand in (dealer_hand, player_hand): # hands to deal to
         deck.deal(hand)
```

This is much more easily adapted to more players and/or more rounds.

Comment: Makes me wonder why they won't touch classes immediately in our programming course :(.

Comment: Some people find them very tricky, but it makes life much harder to do something like cards without them.

Comment: A deck of cards in programming simply a stack. In python, a stack is just a python list. Using a class obfuscates what's actually going on, which is actually one of the features of OO, but once you get proficient at using the standard library, it feels nicer to cut out the class. There's a good talk on this called "stop writing classes" here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0